# Angular CLI not coping images & fonts directory

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm having trouble setting up my *angular-cli.json* to copy the *fonts* and *images* directories from the *@cmsgov* directory within my *node_modules*.

One of the many errors I'm getting in my terminal is `[/Users/user/WebstormProjects/angular-app/src/images/warning.svg]` warning.svg doesn't exist. If needed I can provide more of the error code.

From looking at the documentation for *angular-cli* I should be able to copy the files using this line of code: `{ "glob": "**/*", "input": "../node_modules/some-package/images", "output": "./some-package/" },` but when I try to do this, I keep getting errors. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm currently using angular-cli version *1.4.9*, and I can provide my complete *package.json* if needed

Here is my *angular-cli.json* file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "angular-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        { "glob": "**/*", "input": "../node_modules/@cmsgov/design-system-core/fonts", "output": "./assets/fonts" },
        { "glob": "**/*", "input": "../node_modules/@cmsgov/design-system-core/images", "output": "./assets/images" },
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "sass/styles.scss"
      ],
      "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "../node_modules/"
        ]
      },
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any success ? I am trying to copy the SVG files.. but no success... here is the snippet from angular.json build property: "assets":["src/favicon.ico","src/assets",{"glob": "*.svg","input": "../node_modules/material-design-icons/sprites/svg-sprite/","output": "assets/svg-icons"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your assets are copying correctly. To reference the files you should use the path `assets/images/warning.svg`